# How to remove an svn repository safely/cleanly?

Tags: svn

I created a new SVN repository using the following command:

```
  svnadmin create testrepo
```

This created a repository under /home/myname/svn-repos/ as testrepo with conf.. hooks .. etc under it
Now I no longer need it. Can I just do `rm -rf testrepo`? Or should I do an `svn delete testrepo`. Is there anything else that I should do to keep SVN clean?

I am using svn version 1.7. on centos.

Thanks

Comment: An SVN repository is just a directory with stuff in it. If you delete it, it's not there anymore. I assume that's what you mean by "clean".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just delete it. `svn delete` is a command to use on working copies, not on repositories. You will probably also want to delete any working copies you may have laying around.